# Taylor Series - How do I stop the function when T1 == T0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, format, taylor-series

I am required to make the Taylor Series in python without importing any files like `import math` **nor** using any built-in math functions like `round()`.

My code so far for the cosine function is as such below:

```
x = abs(float(input("Please input the degree: "))) 
rad = x * 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716 / 180

def cos():
    f = 1
    i = 0
    c = 0
    T0 = 1
    T1 = 0
    i = 0
    Tp = 1
    prec = 11
    TDif = 1
    print("{0:^45} {1:^13} {2:^47} {3:>12}".format("x", "termOld", "termNew", "tOld - TNew"))

    while T1 != T0:
        T0 = Tp
        T1 = (-1 * T0 * rad * rad) / ((i + 1) * (i + 2))
        Tp = T1
        f += T1
        c += 1
        i += 2
        TDif = abs(T0) - abs(T1)
        print("{:02d} ==> {:^30.11f} {:^30.11f} {:^30.11f} {:^30.11f}".format(c, f, abs(T0), abs(T1), abs(TDif)))

cos()
```

And here's the output:

```
Please input the degree: 30
                     x                           termOld                        termNew                      tOld - TNew    
01 ==>         0.86292216110                  1.00000000000                  0.13707783890                  0.86292216110         
02 ==>         0.86605388342                  0.13707783890                  0.00313172232                  0.13394611658         
03 ==>         0.86602526410                  0.00313172232                  0.00002861932                  0.00310310300         
04 ==>         0.86602540421                  0.00002861932                  0.00000014011                  0.00002847921         
05 ==>         0.86602540378                  0.00000014011                  0.00000000043                  0.00000013968         
06 ==>         0.86602540378                  0.00000000043                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000043         
07 ==>         0.86602540378                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000         
08 ==>         0.86602540378                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000         
09 ==>         0.86602540378                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000                  0.00000000000
...
```

and the last one repeats until the counter reaches 80.

Now here's my question. How do I stop the function when `termOld` (`T0`) == `termNew` (`T1`) following the precision they are set at, with the conditions set above? Like, I know `T0` is not really `== T1` at counter 9 if you look at the entire decimal, but because the precision is at 11, I want to **stop** it when the strings of just 0's appear as output, i.e. at the counter 07.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `while T1 != T0:` to `while abs(TDif) > .5*10**(-prec):` should do the trick. This ensures that the difference will round down to zero at the given decimal precision.

Comment: That seems to work for deg == 30, and most others, but not for degrees 82 onwards for some reason, unfortunately, but that's the closest I got thus far, thanks!

Output for degrees 82 onwards seems to only load once:

`Please input the degree: 82
                      x                          termOld                        termNew                      tOld - TNew
01 ==>         0.02412376532                  1.00000000000                  1.02412376532                  0.02412376532`

Comment: @HaqeemWan that's very strange. Does it give the expected output with the old loop condition at high angles?

Comment: @MarkSynder Yeah, with the old while loop condition, the original problem arises back, like, the answer is now correct but it still loops way more than I would want it, repeating the strings of just 0's, this time to counter 97

Comment: @HaqeemWan Did you change the value of `prec` without realizing it? That's the only explanation I can think of off the type of my head. After all, `prec` does nothing in your code without my loop condition.

Comment: @MarkSynder That's the strange thing, my prec is still at 11, I ran the exact same code (with your loop condition) with a bunch of values and found that anything under 82 is fine but anything over or equal to 82 only outputs one counter

Comment: @HaqeemWan Oh, I know what the problem is. It's because the second-order term is greater than one, so the first difference is negative. Use `abs(TDif)` instead of just `TDif` in the loop condition.

Comment: @MarkSynder Holy sh*t, that did the trick! Thank you so much, sir. One final question, how did you derive the formulae 5*10**(-prec)? If I ever run into a similar situation, I want to be able to derive a formula like this as you did, once again, thank you

Comment: @HaqeemWan Happy to help. Here's how to arrive at the formula: to be precise to 0 decimals (nearest 1's place), you need to be within .5, so that the rounding will be correct. Then you just extend that rule: to be precise to 1 decimal, your error needs to be one-tenth the size - within .05. So to be precise to prec decimals, you need to be within .5 * (10 to the -prec power), which is 10**(-prec) in python.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

Just a shot in the dark here; if you know what your final answer is going to be around, or what it should be, you could add a termination condition like ...

if T1 == T0:
    break

or use a numerical value in place of a variable comparison.

Then in that instance, if you know what your model should do, and it does do it, you can end the computational process to get there.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. otherwise, my while condition would also be met and it would break. The issue is that python looks at the entire decimal still although I have already formatted it to only 11 d.p's, thanks for answering though